# How does CreateProcess() come to know that new process undergo which subsystem?

Tags: windows

When we build a project, we can define that under which subsystem we want to run our program in windows. But how it would affect the output exe file. Or in other words when we call a CreateProcess() API we just pass it an exe file, So which header inside the exe file, it 
checks to determine that which subsystem going to handle this process? Or it uses some other method in order to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess, i will look into EXE header

[image: PEXE header]

**Look**
http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/ 
http://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-mz.htm

**Tools update:** 
I like: 
http://www.heaventools.com/PE-file-header_viewer.htm 
http://www.mitec.cz/exe.html
You Can: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2010/01/28/how-to-view-the-header-of-an-exe-dll.aspx 
online :http://exe.urih.com/

Comment: which tool you have used to extract these information from exe file?

Answer (score -1):

In the primary header of executable, that information is present. As you are talking about .exe(or rather binary), linker stage is performed. Linker is part of OS, and every OS has a code number through which it is recognized as its binary.

As in case of windows and CreateProcess(), consider reading [this](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/4354a.aspx)